# using "do not do so"

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Is this sentence structure is correct?

> We count the number of members that meet the criteria while their
>   peers do not do so

Will using the following sentence instead provides the same meaning?

> We count the number of members that meet the criteria while their
>   peers do

what I mean by `do not do` or `do not do so`, is they do not meet the criteria.

Comment: Writing advice comment:  "We count the number of members that meet the criteria" is sufficient; adding on a bit that basically means "(but we don't count the members that don't meet the criteria)" is unnecessary.

Comment: I think it is necessary in my case. I am using a general example. But in my case, there is a set of members who meet the criteria and their peers also meet the criteria. The other set is when the set of members meet the criteria but their peers do not do so.

Comment: I need to be precise on whether their peers meet it too or not. Because their is a distinction in my case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, the sentence

> We count the number of members that meet the criteria while their
>   peers do

do not convey the same meaning. You are joining the clauses `members that meet the criteria` and `peers that do not (meet the criteria)` using `while` which is incorrect because the two clauses are not contradictory. [Which is the intended use of the conjunction `while` in this case.]

You could, however, say something like this:

> We count the number of members that meet the criteria but not their
>   peers.

or

> We count the number of members that meet the criteria while their
>   peers do not.

Answer (score 0):

> We count the number of members that meet the criteria while their peers do not do so

This sort of implies that the peers of the members that meet the criteria stand around not counting the members that do meet the criteria.

It's a bit wordy. I think you are implying that you are counting members that meet a criteria. Just say that. Or, you could say that you are counting the members that meet a criteria, during the time that their peers do not meet this criteria. Again, that's a bit wordy, but maybe I'm missing a subtle meaning.

Specifically to your question, "Do not do so" is appropriate but "Do not" may mean the same thing. There is a subtle difference though; "Bobby was messing around; his brothers do not do so" is slightly more correct than "his brothers do not". I guess it's because you can't "Do" mess around, but you can not do so. Sort of guessing.

Unfortunately, a lot of English is the subtle "that doesn't sound right" ...

Hope that helps